# synchronization in JDBC insert statements for web based applications

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, synchronization

I am developing a code where there are a set of insert and select statements. This is a web based application using servlet/jsp. How can i ensure that this method is accessed by one request at a time.

Should I use:

- Synchronized method or Synchronized block

  Or a static synchronize method.

```
public void insertDetails()
{
    //Select Statement

    If  //result of Select statment == "X"
        insert1
    else
        insert 2
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, using synchronized to control database access means "you're doing it wrong".  the database has all kinds of internal mechanisms to control concurrent access, so it is best to use them instead.  among other reasons, using mechanisms in your jvm may limit future ability to scale out or have multiple apps (i.e. have 2 jvms utilizing the same database server's data).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try to modify my insert statement to take care of the `if-else` condition, rather than having a synchronized block.

As jthalborn pointed out, this would ensure proper leverage of your database's internal concurrency-control mechanisms and decouple your logic from having to handle synchronization scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry about commit synchronization as DB Engines are designed to handle that.

Comment: That's indeed answered by jthalborn. How exactly is this answer better? You don't need to repeat already given answers, this isn't a forum or something :)

Comment: I am sorry. But I am new here. Will be taken care of now onwards. Thanks :)